# General Relativity: a question over an integral

Tags: general-relativity, integration

I'm studying GR, and I'm stuck on an integral. The problem is to observe what happens at $r = 2m$, so I find the proper distance (I'm copying all from my professor's notes):

$$\text{d}\ell^2 = \left(1 - \frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}\ \text{d}r^2 ~~~ \to ~~~ \ell = \int_{2m}^r\ \frac{\text{d}r}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{2m}{r}}}$$

Then we study how long it takes to cover the distance:

$$\left(\frac{\text{d}r}{\text{d}s}\right)^2 = E^2 - \left(1 - \frac{2m}{r}\right)\left(1 + \frac{L^2}{r^2}\right) $$

Hence the proper time:

$$s = \int\text{d}s = \int\frac{\text{d}r}{\sqrt{E^2 - \left(1 - \frac{2m}{r}\right)\left(1 + \frac{L^2}{r^2}\right) }}$$

The integral is regular at $r = 2m$, but we want to study the case in which $L = 0$, namely the radial case.
We get:

$$s = \int\frac{\text{d}r}{\sqrt{E^2 - \left(1 - \frac{2m}{r}\right)}}$$

Let's suppose the observer starts from $r = R$ with null velocity: $\left(\frac{\text{d}r}{\text{d}s}\right)_R = 0$

In this way I get $E = 1 - \frac{2m}{R}$ hence

$$ s = \int\frac{\text{d}r}{\sqrt{\frac{2m}{R} - \frac{2m}{r}}} $$

**NOW THE QUESTION**

The professor said it can be solved in a parametric way, setting

$$r = \frac{R}{2}(1 + \cos\eta) ~~~~~~~ \to ~~~~~~~ s = \frac{R}{2}\sqrt{\frac{R}{2m}}(\eta + \sin\eta)$$

But since it's an integration in $r$ I tried to solve it with a normal procedure (I won't write here all the calculation because it was quite long), but my result in the end was:

$$ s = \frac{2m\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2m}{R} - \frac{2m}{r}} - \sqrt{\frac{2m}{R}}}{\sqrt{\frac{2m}{R} - \frac{2m}{r}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2m}{2m - \frac{2mr}{R}}}}\right)}{\left(\frac{2m}{R}\right)^{3/2}} + \frac{r\sqrt{\frac{2m}{R} - \frac{2m}{r}}}{\frac{2m}{R}} + C$$

So the question is:

Why do we solve it via parametric way, when a solution in terms of $r$ exists?

I am pretty sure I have made it all good, I also checked it with Mathematica.

I don't understand why we need to parametrise it.

Thank you, and if you need details, ask me for them. It maybe a mere question of maths but better to be sure.

Comment: What, again, are you asking? It seems like both results are correct. The integral is probably more easy to take in terms of $\eta$, that's why your professor suggests this.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Ok but why? It's just because it's easier or are there any other reasons? I want to know about this. If you are saying it's completely indifferent, then it's ok and I'm done.

Comment: Can you do your integral explicitly without using Mathematica? Probably not (I know I can't). But in terms of $\eta$, it is easy to take. How does Mathematica take this? I dunno, but there is a pretty good possibility that it also passes to some other variable than $r$. Passing to other variables is one of the two useful tricks you can use to do integrals, the other one being integrating by parts.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Actually I did. I used mathematica to check the result once I are at the University but I did the integral by myself. It's just a couple of simple substitution, but that's not the point. I wanted just to know if the parametric way is better because of other reasons or I don't know. Maybe it brings more informations?

Comment: For $r < R$, this solution yeilds a complex answer, since it involves the log of a square root of a negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the integral can be done directly and your result is correct. However, I believe that the parametric form can be more handy and easier to manipulate because of the much simpler form that your solution takes.

I think, however, that there is a mistake in your notes: $\sin(\eta)$ and $\cos(\eta)$ should be substituted by their hyperbolic counterparts in order to obtain the correct parametric curve. No oscillating stuff in this problem!

Tricks of this kind are used to obtained parametric solutions to similar problems as well. For example, in Landau I (Mechanics) the same sort of substitutions are used to give a parametric solution to the Kepler problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So it was just a matter of easiness! Thank you also for pointing out the hyperbolic question. In my notebook I have normal sine, and normal cosine. So thank you!

Comment: Yes, I think it is just a matter of convenience in the end. Good luck with your GR studies!